# c++ How do I print the value of a String attribute of a variable of another type?

Tags: c++, string

I want to display the value of a C++ `String` in the console- but that particular `String` is not defined independently- it is an attribute of a variable of another type... The line that I am currently trying to use to display its value is:

```
printf("\n CSARSixSectorItem.cpp line 530. rm_WPSequence[liSARIndex -1]: %s", rm_WPSequence[liSARIndex-1].rm_RefPointDB->m_Name);
```

Outside the quotes, I am passing the variable: `rm_WPSequence[liSARIndex-1].rm_RefPointDB->m_Name` to the `%s` in the `printf`.

`m_Name` is a variable of type String, defined with:

```
std::string m_Name;
```

`rm_RefPointDB` is a pointer to a `CGenericRefPoint`, defined with:

```
CGenericRefPoint * rm_RefPointDB;
```

and rm_WPSequence is a `vector` defined with:

```
vector< CUserWaypointListElement > rm_WPSequence;
```

However, although the actual variable that I am trying to display is a `string`, when the line is printed in the console, I am not given the contents of the string, but some unreadable characters, such as `L,%`... The characters displayed change every time the line is printed. I am wondering if this is because the `String` is a memeber of another variable? If so, how can I display the value of the String? I don't really want to know anything about its parent variables, but is there something else I need to do to access the String on its own?

Comment: You can't pass non-POD types to variable argument functions like that. You need to call the `c_str` member of `std::string` to retrieve a pointer to the first element of the string since that's what the format specifier is expecting. Increase the warning level on your compiler as it should have issues a warning.

Comment: Your compiler warned you about this.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit I think, that checking actual types of variables passed to `printf()` (and similar) against format specifiers is not required and may not be performed, especially by older compilers.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek: It's not _required_, no.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek It has nothing to do with checking the format specifiers. The warning _should_ have been issued because C++ does not allow you to pass non-POD objects by value to a variable argument function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the c_str() function of std string to pass to %s :

```
printf("\n CSARSixSectorItem.cpp line 530. rm_WPSequence[liSARIndex -1]: %s", rm_WPSequence[liSARIndex-1].rm_RefPointDB->m_Name.c_str());
```

Explanation : %s is expecting a char* type to display. You are passing a std::string which is Class Type .

c_str() returns you a pointer to the char* buffer contained by std::string.

Comment: It returns **const** `char*` pointer, not `char*`. This pointer should be treated as read-only, since modifying it would not update string's internal state.

Comment: It is not. I didn't say anything like that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... This is the first thing I tried, but unfortunately, that doesn't seem to have worked- the print statement now doesn't output anything in the place of the `%s`...

Comment: do you have maybe an empty string ? Make a quick test : assign to m_Name a random string value, such as  "Test", one line before printing ... if in the test everything is ok, then you are not populating your m_Name... if not then this is something weird ... but at least we know what to take into consideration ;)

Answer (score 0):

### The solution

When print a `std::string`, using `printf`'s `%s` format, you should use `c_str()` method of `std::string` as following:

```
rm_WPSequence[liSARIndex-1].rm_RefPointDB->m_Name.c_str()
```

You are using a C-style output way, the `printf`, therefore a C-style parameter should be used to print string.

[`c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) is an member function of `std::string`. It returns a pointer to an array which contains a numm terminated sequence of characters representing the current value of the string object. That is the actual `char` array which hold the character of the name string. This is the C-style of the string,

### Pay attention to compiler's warnings or errors

For this problem, latest stable version of compiler should give you an error. Pay attention to these could save a lot of your time.

For the following test code code, both clang++ and g++ will give an error. They do not allow pass `non-POD` object as `...` for `printf` function call.

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
  string a("This is a string");
  printf("0x%x, 0x%s, 0x%x\n", a, a , &a);
  cout << a << endl;
  return 0;

}
```

Clang++ output

```
$ clang++ Stringcstring.cpp 
Stringcstring.cpp:26:32: error: cannot pass non-POD object of type 'string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') to
      variadic function; expected type from format string was 'unsigned int' [-Wnon-pod-varargs]
  printf("0x%x, 0x%s, 0x%x\n", a, a , &a);
            ~~                 ^
Stringcstring.cpp:26:35: error: cannot pass non-POD object of type 'string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') to
      variadic function; expected type from format string was 'char *' [-Wnon-pod-varargs]
  printf("0x%x, 0x%s, 0x%x\n", a, a , &a);
                  ~~              ^
Stringcstring.cpp:26:35: note: did you mean to call the c_str() method?
  printf("0x%x, 0x%s, 0x%x\n", a, a , &a);
                                  ^
                                   .c_str()
Stringcstring.cpp:26:39: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type
      'string *' (aka 'basic_string<char> *') [-Wformat]
  printf("0x%x, 0x%s, 0x%x\n", a, a , &a);
                        ~~            ^~
1 warning and 2 errors generated.
```

g++ output

```
$ g++ Stringcstring.cpp 
Stringcstring.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Stringcstring.cpp:26:41: error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type ‘std::string {aka class std::basic_string<char>}’ through ‘...’
   printf("0x%x, 0x%s, 0x%x\n", a, a , &a);
                                         ^
Stringcstring.cpp:26:41: error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type ‘std::string {aka class std::basic_string<char>}’ through ‘...’
Stringcstring.cpp:26:41: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 4 has type ‘std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}’ [-Wformat=]
```

### Why you saw meaningless chars output

your object, `rm_WPSequence[liSARIndex-1].rm_RefPointDB->m_Name` is an object of `std::string` class. For `printf`'s `%s` format, what it accept is only an array of `char`,  or it will try to explain your `std::string` object in memory as `char *`, that is why you saw some meaningless chars output.

Comment: I'm surprised it didn't abort at runtime.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comprehensive answer... As mentioned in my comment on the other answer though- this the first thing I tried, but unfortunately, that doesn't seem to have worked- the print statement now doesn't output anything in the place of the %s...